# Delay the Authorization Dialog with GAS Ui Service

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to delay the Authorization Dialog in a stand alone Google Apps Script?
I have a public script that needs to be granted several permissions from the active Google user. I want to tell the user how the script works before asking for all those permissions.

It is not obvious why I need access to all the services, so this dialog looks scary :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts#grantingAccess

My script is a "web app' with the UI Service so the first thing to be displayed comes from doGet(), but the permission dialog opens first. Isn't there a way to delay the dialog **until the permission is actually needed** ?

One possible way would be to call the script from a dedicated website I suppose, but that's not simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to have two web apps:
The first is an 'intro' web app that runs using your account, so it doesn't prompt the user.
Then, you redirect them to a second web app that runs using their account, which will prompt them.